# Titanium TabGroup

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

I am having trouble with tabGroups. I have created a new app (this is my first app) and when I click an option in the table I am calling:

```
win.open(win,{annimated:true});
```

The problem is there is no tab at the top of the page to get back to where I was. So I need to use tabgroups. My question is I am not sure how to use them. When I replace the above with:

```
Ti.UI.currentTab.open(win);
```

I get an error that currentTab is not defined. How do I enable tabGroups? I have another file called AppTabGroup.js that has the: var self = Ti.UI.createTabGroup(); in it but I am not sure how to use it.

Below is the entire page incase I am doing something way off base.

function AppWindow(title) {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title:title,
        backgroundColor:'white'
    });

```
var data = [

{ title:"Catalog", hasChild:true, test:'ui/CatalogWindow.js', header:'' },
{ title:"Service Calculator", hasChild:true, header:'' }
];

var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
data:data,
style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED
});

tableview.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    if (e.rowData.test)
    {
        var win = 
    Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        url:e.rowData.test,
        title:e.rowData.title
    });
    win.open(win,{annimated:true});
}
```

});
      self.add(tableview);

```
return self;
```

};

module.exports = AppWindow;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not alone.  Other people (myself included) have been confused by Ti.UI.currentTab being undefined:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/98501/titaniumuicurrenttab-is-null

The way I've worked around this in the past is to pass down the containing tab to the window, so that it can use that reference to open another window.  So in your example, AppTabGroup.js would look like:

```
var AppWindow = require('src/AppWindow');

var self = Ti.UI.createTabGroup();

//create app tabs
var appTab = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title : L('app'),
    icon : '/images/app_tab.png',
    window : AppWindow
});
AppWindow.setContainingTab(appTab);
```

Then in AppWindow.js:

```
exports.setContainingTab = function(tab) {
    containingTab = tab;
}
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    url:e.rowData.test,
    title:e.rowData.title
});

containingTab.open(win);
```